# how to do change wit sed in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi below is my bash script. which takes a source file and a token file, 
token file contains servicename:usage
I have to find servicename in source file line by line if found then calculate memory usage then change -Xmxm with -Xmx\d{1,3}m.  In below script bold line explain what to do much simple
You can first under stand issue from below small part of script

```
line="Superviser.childOpts:-Xmx128m"
heapMB=750
line=($(echo $line|sed  "s/${-Xmx\d{1,3}m}/$-Xmx{$heapMB}m/g"))
```

So what is the wrong in above line

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceFile=$1

tokenFile=$2

if [ -z $sourceFile ]

then


    echo "Please provide a valid source file"

    exit 0


fi

    if [ -z $tokenFile ]

    then

        echo "Please provide a valid token file"

        exit 0

    fi


#read token file and tokenize with : to get service name at 0 index and percentage usages at 1

declare arr_token_name

declare arr_token_usage

count=0

while read line

do

#here line contain :percentage usages

OIFS="$IFS"

IFS=$':'

arr=($line)

IFS="$OIFS"

if [ ! -z $line ]

then

   arr_token_name[$count]=${arr[0]}

   arr_token_usage[$count]=${arr[1]}

   count=`expr $count + 1`

fi


done 
# read source file line by line test with all the tokens 

totalMemKB=$(awk '/MemTotal:/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)

echo "total mem = $totalMemKB"

while read line

do

result_token_search=""

#for j in "${arr_token_name[@]}"

#do

#   echo "index=$j"

#done

count2=0

for i in "${arr_token_name[@]}"

do

#here search token in line , if found 

#calculate memory for this getting percent usage from arr_token_usage then  use calculate frmula then device by 1024

#then replace -Xmx\d{1,5}m with -Xmx

    echo "line1=$line"

    result_token_search=$(echo $line|grep -P "$i")

    if [ -n "$result_token_search"  ]

    then

        percent_usage=${arr_token_usage[$count2]}

        let heapKB=$totalMemKB*$percent_usage/100

        let heapMB=$heapKB/1024

        echo "before sed=$line"

     line=($(echo $line|sed  "s/${-Xmx\d{1,3}m}/$-Xmx{$heapMB}m/g"))

        echo "new line=$line"

        echo "token found in line $line , token = $i"

    fi

    result_token_search=""


    count2=`expr $count2+1`

    cat "$line" >> tmp.txt

done


done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line:

```
line=$( sed  "s/-Xmx[0-9]\+/-Xmx$heapMB/" <<<$line )
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  line="Superviser.childOpts:-Xmx128m" 

kent$  heapMB=750    

kent$  line=$( sed  "s/-Xmx[0-9]\+/-Xmx$heapMB/" <<<$line )    

kent$  echo $line
Superviser.childOpts:-Xmx750m
```